# Curl in different versions in PHP: one is working, other is not

Tags: php, curl

I am fetching the webpage via **curl** from the one site. The issue is that in one computer it works whereas in other it doesn't work. Here is the code:

```
    $ch = curl_init('https://emea2cps.adobeconnect.com/api/xml?action=login&login=myUser&password=myPassword');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, __DIR__.'/cookies');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, __DIR__.'/cookies');
    curl_exec($ch);
    $info= curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $ch1 = curl_init('https://meet77842937.adobeconnect.com/api/xml?action=report-my-meetings');
    curl_setopt($ch1,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch1,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, __DIR__.'/cookies');
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, __DIR__.'/cookies');
    $data = curl_exec($ch1);
    $info1= curl_getinfo($ch1);
    curl_close($ch1);
```

*Working* on **PHP 5.4.12**, **Curl 7.29.0**

*Not working* on **PHP 5.2.7**, **Curl 7.34.0**

Can you say me where is the problem? And also can you provide me with other ways of fetching webpage that is https and cookie manipulation must be done

With regards

Comment: Any errors/warnings/etc?

Comment: it saids "no login", i guess that i can't login via this commands.

Comment: is your `curl` module is enable in different version ???

Comment: @AkshayPaghdar, yeah it is enabled

Comment: @nurgasemetey Let's hope that's a fake password x)

Comment: @MackieeE, it is temporary account, so it is no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Working in PHP 5.5.5, Curl 7.33.0.  I don't think there's anything wrong with your code.  Is the following executing correctly?

```
function _is_curl_installed() {
  if  (in_array('curl', get_loaded_extensions())) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

echo 'cURL is <b>'.(_is_curl_installed() ? 'installed' : 'not installed').'</b> on this server'.PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: it returns **"cURL is installed on this server"**

Comment: what do you think about it?

Answer (score 0):

Neither Curl nor PHP has changed radically recently. So the versions you have mentioned had no problem to deal with your code. Rather its the issue with permission.

Print this from your php code: `__DIR__.'/cookies'`

And check whether your apache has the write permission on it for both servers(specially at where it doesn't work) or not!

Comment: You lighted this topic, from now I also think that :)

Comment: I will accept answer only after controlling this advice :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the website has some security that prevents other computers (based on IP address, user agents, etc) using the same session identifiers.