# Making two HTTP requests via PHP with file_get_contents to fetch webpage

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am making two HTTP request

**1.** First to login to website

**2.** Second to fetch data from website after succesful login

I guess that  I must send cookies, save returned cookie and retrieve after first http request.

How can I accomplish this?

**UPDATE**: **Curl** is not allowed

With regards!

Comment: and what is the question ?

Comment: Yes, if it uses session based authentication, run it in a browser and look @ the cookie headers.

Comment: @AncientGeek, sorry I forgot it :)

Comment: If you use curl, it has a simple cookie-jar option

Comment: @towr, I am doing it because curl causes problem.It successfully works on computer while it doesn't work on other. So I want to use another method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at similar questions on stackoverflow, without using curl:

**Get cookie:**

[get cookie with file_get_contents in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958491/get-cookie-with-file-get-contents-in-php)

**Send cookie:**

[PHP - Send cookie with file_get_contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431160/php-send-cookie-with-file-get-contents)

Answer (score 0):

using file_get_contents() will only execute a simple GET query to retrieve the webpage.

Take a look at cURL in PHP: https://php.net/curl .

Example at php.net:

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Using the [curl_setopt](https://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) function, with the CURL_COOKIE define, you can create your own Cookie: contents in the HTTP header.

Comment: Sorry, I dont want to use curl, because of various reasons

Comment: What reasons? cURL is made for this stuff.

Comment: problem in following: [myQuestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22095952/curl-in-different-versions-in-php-one-is-working-other-is-not/22096837?noredirect=1#22096837), or in shortly, curl is not working properly on other computers other than my computers

Comment: I replied in that thread.. I don't think you have a problem with cURL not working properly.

Comment: I also think like, stuff like permissions play some role